# Getting error in an array comparing program in a specific input

Tags: c++, arrays, compare, iostream

I have written a small program which compares two arrays with custom array size. Whenever I set the array size to 4, the program does not work correctly on comparing the fourth member of each array.
(when I set x to 4, the fourth array members does not get compared correctly)

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    int i =1;
    int arr[x];
    int arr2[x];
    while(i <= x)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter row " << i << " of arr\n";
        std::cin >> arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    i = 1;
    while(i <= x)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter row " << i << " of arr2\n";
        std::cin >> arr2[i];
        i++;
    }
    for(int a = 0;a <= x;a++)
    {
        if(arr[a] == arr2[a])
            std::cout << "row " << a << " is true\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably not the source of the error but please note that **Variable size arrays** are not supported by C++. `int arr[x];` is OK only if `x` is known at compile time.

Comment: It is. I get the x at line 7 which is before int arr [x];

Comment: It is definitely not known at compile time. You get `x` from the user using`cin`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an out of bound access, which yields undefined behavior. Recall that indices into raw arrays start with **zero**, not with one. Hence,

```
int i = 0;
```

is the correct initialization of the index, while the first loop must be changed to

```
while (i < x) { /* ... */ }
```

Then, the assignment of `i` needs again to be adjusted to

```
i = 0;
```

and the two remaining loops to

```
while (i < x) { /* ... */ }

for (int a = 0; a < x; a++) { /* ... */ }
```

As a side note, you are using variable length arrays (`arr` and `arr2`), which is non-standard C++ (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) for more info). Prefer `std::vector` for a simple container with runtime-dependant size.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1;
while(i <= x)
{
    std::cout << "Enter row " << i << " of arr2\n";
    std::cin >> arr2[i];
    i++;
}
```

you are storing element in array starts with 1 index

```
for(int a = 0;a <= x;a++)
{
    if(arr[a] == arr2[a])
        std::cout << "row " << a << " is true\n";
}
```

But comparing by starting from 0 index.
keep consistency either start from 0 or 1

```
for(int a = 1;a <= x;a++)
{
    if(arr[a] == arr2[a])
        std::cout << "row " << a << " is true\n";
}
```

it will work..